# Trouble implementing pagination with filtering system Next.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I am making this next.js project and I have this one page that displays a large set of data referred to as issues. The issues are shown in cards. Right now the page loads all the cards, then a filtering dropdown allows filtering based on a project name tied to a project id so it filters the whole amount of issues based on the project id, some projects have a lot of cards. I'd like to make it so that no matter what dropdown selection is made, if the project has more than 20 cards it will show 20, and then a load more button which when clicked will show the next 20 cards or remainder of cards for that project. I am not sure how to implement this. I was trying to set an initial pagination value of 20 and then use a function to change the value. Some projects may only have 5 issues so it wouldn't even need to show the load more button for that project, but then some have like 77 which should take three presses of the load more to reveal all the cards. I am not sure if I made this more complicated by breaking down the card section and cards into components. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { useSession } from "next-auth/react";
import Layout from "../components/layout";
import AccessDenied from "../components/access-denied";
import FilterDropdown from "../components/FilterDropdown";
import CardSection from "../components/CardSection";
import NewReportForm from "../components/NewReportForm";
import SuccessMessage from "../components/SuccessMessage";

export default function Admin() {
  const [myIssues, setMyIssues] = useState([]);
  const [projects, setProjects] = useState([]);
  const [states, setStates] = useState([]);
  const [selectedClient, setSelectedClient] = useState("");
  const [selectedProjectName, setSelectedProjectName] = useState("");
  const [selectedCardTitles, setSelectedCardTitles] = useState([]);
  const { data: session } = useSession();
  const [showTextArea, setShowTextArea] = useState(false);
  const [isSubmitting, setIsSubmitting] = useState(false);
  const [userRole, setUserRole] = useState<number | null>(null);
  const [isSuccessMessageVisible, setIsSuccessMessageVisible] = useState(false);
  const [pagination, setPagination] = useState({ first: 20, after: null });

  useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchData() {
      try {
        const res = await fetch("/api/non-db", {
          method: "POST",
          headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
          },
          body: JSON.stringify({
            pagination,
          }),
        });
        const data = await res.json();
        setMyIssues(data.myIssues);
        setProjects(data.projects);
        setStates(data.states);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error retrieving non data:", error);
      }
    }

    fetchData();
  }, [pagination]);

  useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchUserRole() {
      try {
        if (session) {
          const userEmail = session.user.email;
          const userRoleRes = await fetch(
            `/api/user-roles?userEmail=${userEmail}`
          );
          const userRoleData = await userRoleRes.json();
          const userRole = userRoleData.role;
          setUserRole(userRole);
        }
      } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error retrieving user role:", error);
      }
    }

    fetchUserRole();
  }, [session]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (userRole === 1) {
      window.location.href = "/dashboard";
    }
  }, [userRole]);

  const filteredIssues = selectedClient
    ? myIssues.filter((issue) => issue.projectId === selectedClient)
    : myIssues;

  const clients = [
    { id: "", name: "All" },
    ...projects.map((project) => ({
      id: project.id,
      name: project.name || "Unknown Client",
    })),
  ];

  const handleClientChange = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLSelectElement>) => {
    const selectedProjectId = e.target.value;
    setSelectedClient(selectedProjectId);

    const selectedProject = projects.find(
      (project) => project.id === selectedProjectId
    );
    const projectName = selectedProject
      ? selectedProject.name
      : "Unknown Project";
    setSelectedProjectName(projectName);
  };

  const handleNewReportButtonClick = () => {
    const titles = filteredIssues.map((issue) => issue.title);
    const currentDate = new Date().toDateString();
    const reportMessage = `Today's Report: ${currentDate}\n Hello ${selectedProjectName},\n Here are the issues we worked on last week:`;
    const bulletedTitles = titles.map((title) => `• ${title}`);
    const fullReport = [reportMessage, ...bulletedTitles].join("\n");

    setSelectedCardTitles(fullReport);
    setShowTextArea(true);
  };

  const handleSubmit = async (e: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    // Disable the "Save Report" button to prevent duplicate submissions
    if (isSubmitting) {
      return;
    }

    setIsSubmitting(true);

    //const reportMessage = `Hello, here is your Weekly Report for ${selectedProjectName}:\n`;
    const fullReport = selectedCardTitles;

    try {
      const response = await fetch("/api/report-db", {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
          content: fullReport,
          projectName: selectedProjectName,
          projectId: selectedClient,
        }),
      });

      if (response.ok) {
        console.log("Report saved successfully!");

        setIsSuccessMessageVisible(true);
        setTimeout(() => setIsSuccessMessageVisible(false), 3000);
      } else {
        console.error("Error saving report:", response.statusText);
        alert("Error saving report. Please try again later.");
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error saving report:", error);
      alert("Error saving report. Please try again later.");
    } finally {
      setIsSubmitting(false);
    }
  };

  const currentDate = new Date().toDateString();  
  
  console.log(session);
  const getFirstName = (fullName: string) => {
    const firstName = fullName.split(" ")[0];
    return firstName;
  };

  const loadMoreIssues = async () => {
    const lastIssue = filteredIssues[filteredIssues.length - 1];
    const after = lastIssue ? lastIssue.id : null;
    setPagination((prevPagination) => ({ ...prevPagination, after }));
  };

  return (
    <Layout>
      {!session && <AccessDenied />}
      {session && (
        <div className="">
          <h1 className="text-4xl py-2">
            Hello {getFirstName(session.user.name)}
          </h1>
          <div className="text-2xl my-3">Atomic Glue Admin </div>
          <section className="mt-5">
            <FilterDropdown
              selectedClient={selectedClient}
              handleClientChange={handleClientChange}
              clients={clients}
            />
            {filteredIssues.length ? (
              <CardSection filteredIssues={filteredIssues} states={states} />
            ) : (
              <div>No issues found.</div>
            )}
             {filteredIssues.length >= 20 && (
              <section className="mt-5">
                <button
                  onClick={loadMoreIssues}
                  className="bg-gray-200 hover:bg-gray-200 text-green-800 rounded-md px-3 py-2 mt-2"
                >
                  Load More
                </button>
              </section>
            )}
            <div className="text-2xl">
              <button
                className="bg-green-500 hover:bg-green-600 text-white font-bold my-4 py-2 px-4 rounded focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline"
                onClick={handleNewReportButtonClick}
              >
                New Report
              </button>
            </div>
            {showTextArea && selectedCardTitles.length > 0 && (
              <NewReportForm
                selectedProjectName={selectedProjectName}
                currentDate={currentDate}
                selectedCardTitles={selectedCardTitles}
                handleSubmit={handleSubmit}
                isSubmitting={isSubmitting}
                setSelectedCardTitles={setSelectedCardTitles}
              />
            )}

            {isSuccessMessageVisible && (
              <SuccessMessage
                type="Success!"
                message="Your report has been submitted."
              />
            )}
          </section>
        </div>
      )}
    </Layout>
  );
}
```

CardSection component:

```
import React from "react";
import Cards from "../components/cards";

const CardSection = ({ filteredIssues, states }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      {filteredIssues.length ? (
        <div className="">
          <Cards issues={filteredIssues} states={states} />
        </div>
      ) : (
        <div>No issues found.</div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

export default CardSection;
```